# Is there a way to get real time OHLC data for multiple stocks using Interactive Brokers IBAPI library?

Tags: interactive-brokers, ib-api

I am trying to get OHLC for multiple stocks. However I am new to IBAPI and I cannot find any examples where multiple stocks OHLC is fetched simultaneously. This is the code:

```
class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)
    
    def realtimeBar(self, reqId, time:int, open_: float, high: float, low: float, close: float,volume: int, wap: float, count: int):
        super().realtimeBar(reqId, time, open_, high, low, close, volume, wap, count)
        print(RealTimeBar(time, -1, open_, high, low, close, volume, wap, count))

app = TestApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7499, 0)

contract = Contract()
contract.secType = "STK" 
contract.symbol = "XYZ"
contract.currency = "XYZ"
contract.exchange = "XYZ"

app.reqRealTimeBars(1,contract,1,'TRADES',False,[]) 

app.run()
```

Can anyone help me out what I am missing or not getting ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to call reqRealTimeBars multiple times, each with a different contract and request ID. In the realTimeBars callback, you use the request ID to check which contract's data has been received.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino thanks for your suggestion, I will try it and let you know if that works for me

Comment: @MatthewScarpino, hi it worked !! thank you